# Do TCP sockets automatically close after 64kB send?

Tags: c#, .net, networking, tcp

I'm trying to send multiple files over TCP using C# TcpClient, for a file below 64kB it works great, but when I have more it throws an exeption that host-computer disconnected.

Here is my code:

Server side(sending). 
1) SocketServer class

```
public abstract class SocketServer
{
    private Socket serverSocket;

    public SocketServer(IPEndPoint localEndPoint)
    {
        serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        serverSocket.Bind(localEndPoint);
        serverSocket.Listen(0);

        serverSocket.BeginAccept(BeginAcceptCallback, null);
    }

    private void BeginAcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.EndAccept(ar);

        Console.WriteLine("Client connected");

        ClientConnection clientConnection = new ClientConnection(this, clientSocket);
        Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(clientConnection.Process));
        clientThread.Start();

        serverSocket.BeginAccept(BeginAcceptCallback, null);
    }

    internal abstract void OnReceiveMessage(ClientConnection client, byte header, byte[] data);
}
```

Here goes ClientConnection:

```
public class ClientConnection
{
    private SocketServer server;
    private Socket clientSocket;

    private byte[] buffer;
    private readonly int BUFFER_SIZE = 8192;

    public ClientConnection(SocketServer server, Socket clientSocket)
    {
        this.server = server;
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;

        buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    }

    public void Process()
    {
        clientSocket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.Peek, BeginReceiveCallback, null);
    }

    private void BeginReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        int bytesReceived = clientSocket.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesReceived >= 4)
        {
            clientSocket.Receive(buffer, 0, 4, SocketFlags.None);

            // message size
            int size = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);

            // read message 
            int read = clientSocket.Receive(buffer, 0, size, SocketFlags.None);

            // if data still fragmented, wait for it
            while (read < size)
            {
                read += clientSocket.Receive(buffer, read, size - read, SocketFlags.None);
            }

            ProcessReceivedData(size);
        }

        clientSocket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.Peek, BeginReceiveCallback, null);
    }

    private void ProcessReceivedData(int size)
    {
        using (PacketReader pr = new PacketReader(buffer))
        {
            // message header = 1 byte 
            byte header = pr.ReadByte();

            // next message data
            byte[] data = pr.ReadBytes(size - 1);

            server.OnReceiveMessage(this, header, data);
        }
    }

    public void Send(byte[] data)
    {
        // first of all, send message length
        clientSocket.Send(BitConverter.GetBytes(data.Length), 0, 4, SocketFlags.None);

        // and then message
        clientSocket.Send(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None);
    }
}
```

Implementation of FileServer class:

```
public class FileServer : SocketServer
{
    string BinaryPath;

    public FileServer(IPEndPoint localEndPoint) : base(localEndPoint) 
    {
        BinaryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    }

    internal override void OnReceiveMessage(ClientConnection client, byte hdr, byte[] data)
    {
        // Convert header byte to ENUM
        Headers header = (Headers)hdr;

        switch(header)
        {
            case Headers.Queue:
                Queue(client, data);
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong header received {0}", header);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void Queue(ClientConnection client, byte[] data) 
    {
        // this message contains fileName
        string fileName = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 1, data.Length - 1);

        // combine path with assembly location
        fileName = Path.Combine(BinaryPath, fileName);
        if (File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);
            long fileLength = fileInfo.Length;

            // pass the message that is now start a file transfer, contains:
            // 1 byte = header
            // 16 bytes = file length
            using (PacketWriter pw = new PacketWriter())
            {
                pw.Write((byte)Headers.Start);
                pw.Write(fileLength);
                client.Send(pw.GetBytes());
            }

            // 
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                int read = 0, offset = 0;
                byte[] fileChunk = new byte[8191];
                while (offset < fileLength)
                {
                    // pass message with file chunks, conatins
                    // 1 byte = header
                    // 8195 bytes = file chunk
                    using (PacketWriter pw = new PacketWriter())
                    {
                        fs.Position = offset;
                        read = fs.Read(fileChunk, 0, fileChunk.Length);
                        pw.Write((byte)Headers.Chunk);
                        pw.Write(fileChunk, 0, read);
                        client.Send(pw.GetBytes());
                    }

                    offset += read;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And helper classes:

```
public class PacketWriter : BinaryWriter
{
    private MemoryStream memoryStream;

    public PacketWriter() : base()
    {
        memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        OutStream = memoryStream;
    }

    public byte[] GetBytes()
    {
        byte[] data = memoryStream.ToArray();

        return data;
    }
}

public class PacketReader : BinaryReader
{
    public PacketReader(byte[] data) : base(new MemoryStream(data))
    {
        binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    }
}
```

Client have the almost same code. Except receive:

```
internal override void OnReceiveMessage(ServerConnection client, byte hdr, byte[] data)
{
    Headers header = (Headers)hdr;

    switch(header)
    {
        case Headers.Start:
            Start(data); // save length of file and prepare for receiving it
            break;
        case Headers.Chunk:
            Chunk(data); 
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong header received {0}", header);
            break;
    }
}

private void Chunk(byte[] data)
{
    // Process reveived data, write it into a file
}
```

Comment: What's the data type of `fileLength`?

Comment: `fileLength` is integer

Comment: That's not a type, it's a whole group of types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do TCP sockets automatically close after 64kB send?

No, TCP sockets do not automatically close after 64 KB of sent data, nor after *any* amount of sent data. They remain open until either end closes the connection or a network error of some sort happens.

Unfortunately, your question is extremely vague, providing practically no context. But I will point out one potentially serious bug in your client code: you are not restricting the data read by the client to that which you expect for the current file. If the server is sending more than one file, it is entirely possible and *likely* that on reaching the end of the data for the current file, a read containing that final sequence of bytes will also contain the initial sequence of bytes for the next file.

Thus, the expression `totalBytesRead == fileLenght` will fail to ever be `true` and your code will attempt to read all of the data the server sends as if it's all part of the first file.

One easy way to check for this scenario is to look at the size of the file that was written by the client. It will be much larger than expected, if the above is the issue.

You can fix the code by only ever receiving at most the number of bytes you actually expect to be remaining:

```
while ((bytesRead = binaryReader.Read(
    buffer, 0, Math.Min(fileLenght - totalBytesRead, buffer.Length))) > 0)
{
    fs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

    totalBytesRead += bytesRead;

    if (totalBytesRead == fileLenght)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

While you're at it, you might fix the spelling of the variable named `fileLenght`. I know Intellisense makes it easy to type the variable name whether it's spelled right or not, but if you one day have to grep through the source code looking for code that involves itself with "length" values, you'll miss that variable.

**EDIT:**

Having pointed out the problem in the code you posted with your question originally, I now find myself looking at completely different code, after your recent edit to the question. The example is still not [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and so advice will still have to be of a limited nature. But I can see at least two major problems in your receive handling:

1. You are mixing `Receive()` and `BeginReceive()`. This is probably not *too* terrible in general; what makes it really bad in your case is that *in the completion handler for the initial asynchronous receive*, you are blocking the thread while you use the synchronous `Receive()` to (attempt to) receive the rest of the data, and then to make matters worse, in the `FileServer` case you continue to block that thread while you *transmit* the file data to the client.
   I/O completion handlers must *not* block the thread for any significant amount of time; they must retrieve the data for the completed operation, and return as quickly as is feasible. There's a lot of wiggle room, but not enough to justify tying up the IOCP thread for the entire file transfer.
2. While the first issue is bad, it's probably not bad enough to actually cause the connection to reset. In a low-volume scenario, and especially if you're just dealing with one client at a time at the moment, I doubt blocking the IOCP thread that's being used to call your I/O completion callback will cause any easily observable problems.
   What's much worse is that you allocate the `buffer` array once, with a length of 8192, and then proceed to attempt to stuff the entire counted-byte stream of bytes being sent. On the assumption that the client will be sending short messages, this is probably fine on the server side. But on the client side, the value of `size` can easily be greater than the 8192 bytes allocated in the `buffer` array.
   I find it very likely that your `BeginReceiveCallback()` method is throwing an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` after receiving the first 8192 bytes, due to the fact that you are passing the `Receive()` method a `size` value that exceeds the length of the `buffer` array. I can't *prove* that, because the code example is incomplete. You'll have to follow up on that theory yourself.

As long as I'm reviewing the code you posted, some other irregularities stood out as I scanned through it:

1. It's a bit odd to be using a buffer length of 8191 when transmitting the file.
2. Your `BeginReceiveCallback()` method discards whatever bytes were sent initially. You call `EndReceive()`, which returns the count of bytes received, but the code that follows assumes that the `size` value in the stream is still waiting to be read, when it very easily could have been sent in the first block of bytes. Indeed, your comparison `bytesReceived >= 4` seems to be intended to refrain from processing received data until you have that length value. Which is wrong for another reason:
3. If your header is 1 byte followed by a 4-byte count-of-bytes value, then you really need `bytesReceived > 4`. But worse, TCP is allowed to drip out a single byte at a time if it really wants to (it won't, but if you write your code correctly, it won't matter). Since you only process received data if you get at least 4 bytes, and since if you don't get 4 bytes, you just ignore whatever was sent so far, you could theoretically wind up ignoring *all* of the data that was sent.

That you have the risk that *any* data could be ignored at all is terrible. But #2 above *guarantees* it, and #3 just adds insult to injury.

4. When receiving the `size` value, you are reading a 32-bit integer, but when *sending* the `size` value (i.e. for the file itself), you are writing a 64-bit integer. You'll get the right number on the receiving end, because `BinaryWriter` uses little-endian and that means that the first four bytes of any 64-bit integer less than 2^31 are identical to the four bytes of the 32-bit integer representation of the same number. But you'll still wind up with four extra zero bytes after that; if treated as file data as they likely would, that would corrupt your file.

Comment: Yes, this code not perfect, but it works. The main question is why the connection is breakes after sending 64kB. Actually, the inner buffer size of TCP is 64kB, but how can i clear the data from it? Server send "packet" or "chunk" (I know, TCP using streams) with length for example of 1024 bytes (TCP buffer increments now by 1024 bytes). That data starts traver to the client. Client receives that chunk and append to file. These steps are repeated several times, and TCP buffer grows. Why? Data data has been **sent** and **received**! I have more complex and clean code, this is just example

Comment: _"but it works"_ -- I disagree. You wouldn't have posted your question if the code worked, and I've described above in my answer at least one important way in which it _doesn't_ work (as well as answered original question of whether TCP sockets close automatically). Without a more complete code example and better context, it's not possible to offer more specific advice than the above. But there's enough in your question to know for sure the code doesn't in fact work.

Comment: As for the specific question in your comment about "TCP buffer", it's not clear to me _which_ buffer you are talking about. But if you are somehow examining the underlying implementation of the TCP protocol in the network stack, keep in mind that TCP includes a "window" that allows transmitted data to get ahead of acknowledged data; this requires an intermediate buffer that will fill over time before reaching its maximum length, and then empty only as the last bytes are received by the client.

Comment: I got ErrorCode 10053 for this "host-computer disconnected" exception. Still I can not solve the problem, any idea how to send file in _Right_ way?

Comment: _"any idea how to send file in Right way"_ -- what did you think my answer above is for? Have you tried my proposed fix to your code? Since you haven't provided a good [mcve], I have no knowledge of any other specific problems in your code, but the above will fix the one obvious problem I do see. You should start there; if you have additional problems, post a new question, providing a good code example.

Comment: The new code you posted is completely different from the code you had originally included. If that's the code you're actually using, then why did you post completely different code before? If you have completely different code you want to ask a question about, you should post a new question, not completely change the question you've already asked (especially not after it's been answered). I will add a bit to my answer above, to address the couple of obvious problems I see in your newest version of your code. But until you provide a good [mcve], this will have to do.